# Meteor query with map method, trying to set index to last element instead of first

Tags: javascript, dictionary, indexing, meteor

I have the following code that I am using to exclude certain items in a collection on index 0, however I would like to to the opposite and exclude them at the last index number which keeps changing as i add content, I am not sure how to do that. So lets say there are 4 index items i want index === 4 dynamically. I have tried changing my sort order to 1 from -1 one in the query but for some reason that doesn't change the order so Im not sure how to approach this.

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({
      posts: function() {
      var test =
        Posts
            .find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1, title:1, message:1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}})
            .map(function(post, index) {


              if (index === 0) {

                delete post.thumb;
                delete post._id;
                delete post.title;
                delete post.message;
                return post;

                } else {
                delete post.url;
                //console.log(post);
                return post;
              }
            });

            //var b = test.splice(1,1);

            //console.log(b);



            return test;
        }



    });
```

UPDATE CODE

```
Template.motionPictures.helpers({


    var posts = Posts.find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1, title:1, message:1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch();
    var last = _.last(posts);

    delete last.thumb;


    return posts;



});
```

ERROR

```
While building the application:
client/views/posts/posts_lists.js:61:9: Unexpected identifier
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to fetch the posts:

```
var posts = Posts.find(...).fetch();
var last = _.last(posts);

delete last.thumb;
...

return posts;
```

Comment: I am a little lost in what to put in the .find(...) i put in my same code in there and it gave me a error, could you expand possibly. Thnaks

Comment: It should be the same thing as what you had before, i.e. `find({}, {fields: {thumb: 1, url: 1, title:1, message:1}, sort: {createdAt: -1}})`. What's the error you got?